# spark save taking lot of time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I've 2 dataframes and I want to find the records with all columns equal except 2 (surrogate_key,current)

And then I want to save those records with new surrogate_key value.

Following is my code :

```
val seq = csvDataFrame.columns.toSeq
var exceptDF = csvDataFrame.except(csvDataFrame.as('a).join(table.as('b),seq).drop("surrogate_key","current"))
exceptDF.show()

exceptDF = exceptDF.withColumn("surrogate_key", makeSurrogate(csvDataFrame("name"), lit("ecc")))
exceptDF = exceptDF.withColumn("current", lit("Y"))

exceptDF.show()

exceptDF.write.option("driver","org.postgresql.Driver").mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(postgreSQLProp.getProperty("url"), tableName, postgreSQLProp)
```

This code gives correct results, but get stuck while writing those results to postgre.

Not sure what's the issue. Also is there any better approach for this??

Regards,
Sorabh

Comment: Also the show() before writing to postgre prints the dataframe correctly, but then writing takes too much time.

Comment: `show` won't execute your transformation on the entire data, it will just take how much data it needs to show (which is 20 by default). You need to perform cache + action before writing into postgres then you can measure how much time it's actually taking to writing into postgres. Also "lot of time" is a very broad description, how much data to you have and how much time is it actually taking...

Comment: Hi Eliasah, I used cache() + count(), its taking around 1/2 hr for just 3 rows of 10 columns, Also the delay is not due to writing in postgre. After adding count(), its the count() that's taking time now.

Comment: Which excludes the fact that it's saving that is taking time.

Comment: Your whole pipeline needs to be profiled then... We can't help you much with the current information and code that you have given

Comment: Saving DataFrame as CSV or Parquet is faster than JDBC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Default spark-sql creates 200 partitions, which means when you are trying to save the datafrmae it will be saved in 200 parquet files. you can reduce the number of partitions for Dataframe using below techniques.

1. At application level. Set the parameter "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" as follows :

`sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10")`

2. Reduce the number of partition for a particular DataFrame as follows :

`df.coalesce(10).write.save(...)`

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, That helped..:)

Answer (score -1):

Using the `var` for dataframe are not suggested, You should always use `val` and create a new Dataframe after performing some transformation in dataframe.

Please remove all the `var` and replace with `val`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Shankar.  Even after changing var to val the issue still exists.